# How can I limit a spatial binning query to a specific bounding box?

Tags: sql, hadoop

I am using Esri's GIS tools for Hadoop but I think the query is pretty standard stuff.  The SQL/HQL below is from the Esri tutorial found here https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/wiki/Aggregating-CSV-Data-%28Spatial-Binning%29

So I have a datastore of millions of points but I only want to produce a map of a specific region (say Europe).

The query I currently run generates a Spatial bin of the entire world

```
FROM (SELECT ST_Bin(0.001, ST_Point(dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude)) bin_id, *FROM taxi_demo) bins
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE taxi_agg
SELECT ST_BinEnvelope(0.001, bin_id) shape, COUNT(*) count
GROUP BY bin_id;
```

How would I limit this to a specific bounding box?  Any Ideas?

EDIT: including solution for reference (UK envelope):

```
SELECT ST_Bin(0.001, ST_Point(coordinates.coordinates[0],coordinates.coordinates[1])) bin_id, *FROM data_final
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Envelope(ST_Polygon(-11.115,49.511, 2.537,49.511, 2.537,59.41, -11.115,59.41, -11.115,49.511)), ST_Point(coordinates.coordinates[0],coordinates.coordinates[1]))
```

Comment: Please **edit** the question to contain the exact bounding box values you want to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can limit the extent of your result by adding a filter to the select from `taxi_demo`.

Change...

```
SELECT ST_Bin(0.001, ST_Point(dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude)) bin_id, *FROM taxi_demo
```

to something like...

```
SELECT ST_Bin(0.001, ST_Point(dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude)) bin_id, *FROM taxi_demo 
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Envelope([xmin],[ymin],[xmax],[ymax]), ST_Point(dropoff_longitude,dropoff_latitude))
```

Comment: Thanks climbage, that worked a treat!.  I recognise you from the github repos, you're doing a great job and I love the Hadoop integration - bit of a learning curve but worth it!  Edited original post to include my solution! Cheers